# Failure in running Python script using a cron

Tags: python-2.7, freebsd

I am using the FreeBSD variant as seen below:

```
[2.2.4-RELEASE][root@ROUTER.local]/home/Script_to_monitor_power: uname -a
FreeBSD ROUTER.local 10.1-RELEASE-p15 FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE-p15 #0 c5ab052(releng/10.1)-dirty: Sat Jul 25 20:20:58 CDT 2015     root@pfs22-amd64-builder:/usr/obj.amd64/usr/pfSensesrc/src/sys/pfSense_SMP.10  amd64
```

I have written a python script that runs sucessfully using the below commnd in CLI:

```
 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/Script_to_monitor_power/power_alarm_t2.py
```

The python script contains a shebang line as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

The location of python2.7 is as below:

```
[2.2.4-RELEASE][root@ROUTER.local]/home/Script_to_monitor_power: where python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

My objective is to run the above script as a cronjob.
So i make my script executable using

```
[2.2.4-RELEASE][root@ROUTER.local]/home/Script_to_monitor_power: chmod +x power_alarm_t2.py
```

I have the edited the crontab as below:

```
[2.2.4-RELEASE][root@ROUTER.local]/home/Script_to_monitor_power: crontab -l
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /home/Script_to_monitor_power/power_alarm_t2.py
```

I also do:

```
[2.2.4-RELEASE][root@ROUTER.local]/home/Script_to_monitor_power: cron reload
cron: cron already running, pid: 43420
```

Now when i do:

```
[2.2.4-RELEASE][root@ROUTER.local]/home/Script_to_monitor_power:   ps -ef | grep cron
```

Q: My cronjob is not running after every 1 min. Please suggest what am i missing?

Comment: Make your script executable 'chmod +x /home/Script_to_monitor_power/power_alarm_t2.py'

Comment: already tried, no luck

Comment: Try this structure */1 * * * * /home/Script_to_monitor_power/power_alarm_t2.py

Comment: tried this as well

Answer (score 1):

Check PATH, per default /usr/local/bin is not in root's PATH.